# Universal Icon for Religion

Tags: icon, symbolism, best-practice, user-experience

Is there a culturally-universal symbol to represent religion or a place of worship?

I would like to avoid having an icon containing multiple religious symbols because that opens up a whole mess of problems and which symbols to show would depend a lot on the cultural of the viewer.